# Global variables and multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have about 100 processes that run concurrently for ~ 12 hours. Each time a processes accomplishes a goal I want to add +1 to a global counter. I have a discord chat that can interact with my script that gives me updates on how many "goals" my script has accomplished.

I previously used multi-threading w/ globals but I maxed out my cpu on one core and switched to multi-processing.

Most of the solutions I find are for processes in which the desired output is received only at the end of the script execution. For my script, however, I want to find the "goals" it accomplishes in real time while the processes are still running. I was thinking of storing and accessing environmental variables but was hoping there would be a more eloquent way.

Comment: you may find this relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation on how to share state across your processes? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that is just what I am looking for, thank you so much!